# ADAL to MSAL Migration Securing Web API

Tags: .net, angular, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I'm working on a project for migrating ADAL to MSAL. The UI part is Angular and the Web API is .Net Framework 4.7.2.
In Startup.Auth.cs, I see the codes works perfectly on validating the incoming API request. But when I change the token acquiring from MSAL in Angular and send the bear token to the API, the API is not able to tell the user is authenticated and not able to tell who is the user anymore(it will always returns false).

I see many example from .net Core, is there a good way to make the change in .net Framework?

```
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var constants = UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer().Resolve<IConstants>();
            app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
                new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    Tenant = constants.TenantId,
                    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidAudiences = new List<string> { constants.Audience, constants.ClientId}
                    },
                    AuthenticationType = "OAuth2Bearer",
                    AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active
                });

        }
```

Answer (score -1):

U can use my nuget, MSALTokenGeneratorv3.

public static async Task ConfidentialClientBuilderApp(string resource = null, string clientId = null,
string clientSecret = null, string authority = null, IEnumerable scopes = null)
{
// We will use MSAL.NET to get a token to call the API On Behalf Of the current user
try
{
// Creating a ConfidentialClientApplication using the Build pattern (https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Client-Applications)
ExponentialRetryStrategy retryStrategy = new ExponentialRetryStrategy();

```
                _confidentialClientApp = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
                    .WithAuthority(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, authority))
                    .WithClientSecret(clientSecret).WithLegacyCacheCompatibility(false)
                    .Build();

                // In memory distributed token cache
                _confidentialClientApp.AddInMemoryTokenCache();

                // Acquiring an AuthenticationResult for the scope user.read, impersonating the user represented by userAssertion, using the OBO flow
                await RetryHelper.RetryAsync(async () =>
                {
                    _authenticationResult = await _confidentialClientApp.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                }, (exception) =>
                {
                    return true;
                }, retryStrategy.ShouldRetry(), new Action<Exception, RetryErrorType, int>(LogTokenGenerationFailure)).ConfigureAwait(false);

                if (_authenticationResult != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_authenticationResult.AccessToken))
                    accessToken = _authenticationResult.AccessToken;

                if (accessToken == null)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Access Token could not be acquired.");
                }

                return accessToken;
            }
            catch (MsalUiRequiredException)
            {
                /*
                * If you used the scope `.default` on the client application, the user would have been prompted to consent for Graph API back there
                * and no incremental consents are required (this exception is not expected). However, if you are using the scope `access_as_user`,
                * this exception will be thrown at the first time the API tries to access Graph on behalf of the user for an incremental consent.
                * You must then, add the logic to delegate the consent screen to your client application here.
                * This sample doesn't use the incremental consent strategy.
                */
                throw;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
    }
```

public static async Task PublicClientBuilderApp(IEnumerable scope, string tenantId, string clientId = null,
string userName = null, string password = null)
{
ConvertStringToSecureString convertToSecureString = new ConvertStringToSecureString();
ExponentialRetryStrategy retryStrategy = new ExponentialRetryStrategy();

```
        // We will use MSAL.NET to get a token to call the API On Behalf Of the current user
        try
        {
            _publicClientApp = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId).WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, 
                tenantId).WithLegacyCacheCompatibility(false).Build();

            // Acquiring an AuthenticationResult for the scope user.read, impersonating the user represented by userAssertion, using the OBO flow
            await RetryHelper.RetryAsync(async () =>
            {
                //To clear the token cache every time the new request comes , else it uses cached userassertion
                var accounts = await _publicClientApp.GetAccountsAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

                IEnumerator<IAccount> enumerator = accounts.GetEnumerator();
                while (enumerator.Current != null)
                {
                    await _publicClientApp.RemoveAsync(enumerator.Current).ConfigureAwait(false);

                }
                // Acquiring an AuthenticationResult for the scope user.read, impersonating the user represented by userAssertion, using the OBO flow
                _authenticationResult = await _publicClientApp.AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword(scope, userName, convertToSecureString.StringToSecureString(password)).ExecuteAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            }, (exception) =>
            {
                return true;
            }, retryStrategy.ShouldRetry(), new Action<Exception, RetryErrorType, int>(LogTokenGenerationFailure)).ConfigureAwait(false);

            if (_authenticationResult != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_authenticationResult.AccessToken))
                accessToken = _authenticationResult.AccessToken;

            if (accessToken == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Access Token could not be acquired.");
            }

            return accessToken;
        }
        catch (MsalUiRequiredException)
        {
            /*
            * If you used the scope `.default` on the client application, the user would have been prompted to consent for Graph API back there
            * and no incremental consents are required (this exception is not expected). However, if you are using the scope `access_as_user`,
            * this exception will be thrown at the first time the API tries to access Graph on behalf of the user for an incremental consent.
            * You must then, add the logic to delegate the consent screen to your client application here.
            * This sample doesn't use the incremental consent strategy.
            */
            throw;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    public static void LogTokenGenerationFailure(Exception exception, RetryErrorType errorType, int retryCount)
    {
    }
```

Comment: your code formatting is not very consistent in this answer (some of it ended up as regular text).  Can you fix the markdown for the C# code?  Also, you should probably add a bit of information on what exactly is it that your package does, what license it has, and whether it is open source, etc.  Looking on Nuget, there's no link to a project website or repo.  Thanks!

Comment: very good feedback, will be updating it over the weekend, Thank you so much for pointing it out.